# Register click listener on ckeditor5 dropdown items

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am currently trying to write a plugin for the [CKEditor 5](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/) to support automatic translations. I was able to find out [how to write plugins](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/creating-simple-plugin.html) and how to create dropdowns in the documentation.

But in the documentation there is no mention (or I missed it) how to be informed about a click on the values:

- There is an Execute Handler for the button that opens the dropdown, but how do I register a listener for a click on one of the values?
- Can I assign an `id` or similar to my items to recognize the click on the right element of the dropdown?

Here's the code that I was able to build based on the documentation:

```js
class Translation extends Plugin {
    init() {
        this.editor.ui.componentFactory.add('translate', (locale) => {
            const dropdownView = createDropdown(locale);
            dropdownView.buttonView.set({
                icon: languageIcon,
                label: 'Translate',
                tooltip: true,
            });

            const items = new Collection();
            items.add({
                id: 'en', // how to assign id ???
                type: 'button',
                model: new Model({
                    withText: true,
                    label: 'English'
                }),
            });
            items.add({
                id: 'es', // how to assign id ???
                type: 'button',
                model: new Model({
                    withText: true,
                    label: 'Spanish'
                }),
            });
            addListToDropdown(dropdownView, items);

            // callback for click on item ????
            dropdownView.on('click', (event) => {
                console.log('click', event);
            });

            return dropdownView;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [DropdownView.on()](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_ui_dropdown_dropdownview-DropdownView.html#function-on) method to listen to the `execute` event.

And, use [EventInfo.source](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_utils_eventinfo-EventInfo.html#member-source) property to get the object that is clicked and then use its property e.g. `id` or `label` to identify it.

For example:

```js
const items = new Collection();
items.add( {
    type: 'button',
    model: new Model({
        id: 'en',                // id 
        withText: true,
        label: 'English',
    })
} );
items.add( {
    type: 'button',
    model: new Model({
        id: 'es',               // id
        withText: true,
        label: 'Spanish'
    })
} );

addListToDropdown(dropdownView, items);

dropdownView.on('execute', (eventInfo) => {
    const { id, label } = eventInfo.source;

    if ( id === 'en' ) {
        console.log('Object (en):', label);
    } else if ( id === 'es' ) {
        console.log('Object (es):', label);
    }
});
```

Here's the complete working example with `ClassicEditor` (tested):

```js
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import Model from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/model';
import Collection from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/collection';
import { createDropdown, addListToDropdown } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/dropdown/utils';
import Plugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin';

const Translate = 'translate';

class Translation extends Plugin {
    init() {
        console.log('Translation initialized!');

        this.editor.ui.componentFactory.add(Translate, (locale) => {
            const dropdownView = createDropdown(locale);
            dropdownView.buttonView.set({
                label: 'Translate',
                withText: true,
            });

            const items = new Collection();
            items.add( {
                type: 'button',
                model: new Model({
                    id: 'en',
                    withText: true,
                    label: 'English',
                })
            } );
            items.add( {
                type: 'button',
                model: new Model({
                    id: 'es',
                    withText: true,
                    label: 'Spanish'
                })
            } );

            addListToDropdown(dropdownView, items);

            dropdownView.on('execute', (eventInfo) => {
                const { id, label } = eventInfo.source;

                if ( id === 'en' ) {
                    console.log('Object (en):', label);
                } else if ( id === 'es' ) {
                    console.log('Object (es):', label);
                }
            });

            return dropdownView;
        });
    }
}

ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        plugins: [ Essentials, Translation ],
        toolbar: [ Translate ]
    } )
    .then( editor => {
        console.log( 'Editor was initialized', editor );
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error.stack );
    } );
```

Console output after clicking both items:

```
Object (en): English
Object (es): Spanish
```

Comment: Thank you for the working example! I rewarded you the bounty instead of Kiran who was a little bit faster because you also solved my second problem on how to get the id of the selected dropdown ;)

Comment: @TobiasP.: You're welcome! It was a learning experience for me as well. The `execute` event is delegated from `ButtonView` to `ListView` to `DropdownView` in the `addListToDropdown()`. And, from the `items`, only `type` and `model` properties are used by `bind()` method internally. You can dive in a little bit with the debugging to see how it all works. It was fun! ;) Good luck with your plugin! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[execute](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_ui_dropdown_dropdownview-DropdownView.html#event-execute)**. it will fire an event when the toolbar button or list item is executed.for listView It fires when a child of some **ListItemView** fired execute. for **toolbarView** It fires when one of the buttons has been executed. execute will return [EventInfo](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_utils_eventinfo-EventInfo.html) object when event fires. Also, there is off() and stop() method to de-register the event listener.

> Note: Only supported when dropdown has list view added using **addListToDropdown** or **addToolbarToDropdown**.

Here is the snippet, give it a try.

```js
this.listenTo( dropdownView, 'execute', eventInfo => {
    console.log(eventInfo.source);
} );
```

----------------------------------------------------------- OR ------------------------------------------------------------------

```js
dropdownView.on('execute', eventInfo => {
    console.log(eventInfo.source);
} );
```

Comment: I already tried the execute listener. If you replace the `click` with `execute` in my code the callback will be called but only __once__ for the click on the toolbar button of the dropdown, not for the list items.

Comment: @TobiasP. try the given code snippet, just replacing `on` with `execute` won't work.

Comment: Thank you Kiran for the answer. But i rewarded Azeem the bounty despite being a little bit slower because he also solved my second problem on how to get the id of the selected dropdown ;) If it would be possible i would have given you the bounty too.

Comment: @TobiasP. Never mind, It worths you believe me eligible for a bounty. :-)