# How to retrieve the value from a dropdown created in a ckeditor5 view class from the UI class & react to user input

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor5

I'm writing a custom plugin for ckeditor 5 which will insert an iframe.  For styling purposes we need to ask what the position of the iframe should be (middle/left/right).  We want to do this with an alignment dropdown in the bubble.  Adding the dropdown is no problem:

```js
    // we do this in the View class, so it extends ckeditor5/src/ui/View
    _createDropdown( label, options ) {
        const dropdown = createDropdown( this.locale );

        dropdown.buttonView.set( {
            label,
            withText: true
        } );

        const items = new Collection();

        options.forEach( option => {
            items.add( {
                type: 'button',
                model: new Model( {
                    icon: option.icon,
                    label: option.text,
                    withText: true
                } )
            } );
        } );

        addListToDropdown( dropdown, items );
        dropdown.render();

        return dropdown;
    }
```

This portrays the dropdown visual in the contextballoon.  However, when i select one of the items in the dropdown, nothing happens: i can't find out how to retrieve the value nor even how to show the user choice.  By default it doesn't do anything except open/close the dropdown when the user clicks on it.

I need to access the value in the UI class, but the line for the alignment doesn't work.

```js
    // UI class, extends Plugin
            this.listenTo( iframeView, 'submit', () => {
            const url = iframeView.urlInput.fieldView.element.value;
            const width = iframeView.widthInput.fieldView.element.value;
            const height = iframeView.heightInput.fieldView.element.value;
            const alignment = iframeView.alignmentDropdown.buttonView.element.value;
            const showScrollBars = iframeView.showScrollbarsToggle.fieldView.element.value;
            const showBorders = iframeView.showBorderToggle.fieldView.element.value;
            const name = iframeView.nameInput.fieldView.element.value;
            const title = iframeView.advisoryTitleInput.fieldView.element.value;
            const description = iframeView.longDescriptionInput.fieldView.element.value;
            ...
```

Does anyone know how to:

1. persist the choice the user made, so in other words react to the execute event somehow
2. retrieve the value in the UI class

Comment: I made a ticket for this, as it seems like a bug: 

https://github.com/FTRPRF/ftrprf-monorepo/pull/1246#pullrequestreview-1247856887

Comment: Have you seen this page? It also asks about dropdowns and handlers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505343/register-click-listener-on-ckeditor5-dropdown-items

Comment: Thanks @pmagunia ... I was having the same trouble (and concern) trying to convert over a select input in a Drupal CK form.  It seems a lot of work for something that should be 'simple'

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, but it seems like this cannot possibly be the right way to do it, so anyone with a better idea:

```js
// this is in IframeView.js
_createDropdown( label, options ) {
  const dropdown = createDropdown( this.locale );
  const buttons = {};
  const labelButton = {
    label,
    withText: true
  };
  
  dropdown.buttonView.set( labelButton );
  
  const items = new Collection();
  
  options.forEach( option => {
    const buttonObject = {
      type: 'button',
      option,
      model: new Model( {
      class: option.className,
      icon: option.icon,
      label: option.text,
      withText: true
      } )
    };
    buttons[ option.text ] = buttonObject;
    items.add( buttonObject );
  } );
  
  addListToDropdown( dropdown, items );
  
  this.listenTo( dropdown, 'execute', evt => {
    const choice = evt.source.element.textContent;
    const buttonOptions = buttons[ choice ].option;
    dropdown.buttonView.label = `Align ${ buttonOptions.text }`;
    dropdown.buttonView.icon = buttonOptions.icon;
    this.ui._setAlignment( choice );  // this sets a property on the IframeUi
  } );
  
  dropdown.render();
  return dropdown;
}
```

And in IframeUi.js:

```js
// in init:
this.alignment = '';

_setAlignment( alignment ) {
  this.alignment = alignment;
}
```